# How to println value from function?

Tags: java, output, void

I would like to println value 5 from void add_up but I cant write name of function: add_up to System out.println(). How to println out of main and get out of void add_up?  Thank´s.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class function{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            System.out.println(add_up);

    }

    public int add_up(){
    int a = 5;
    return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to invoke the non-static method from the `static` main method. If you were to make the `add_up` method `static`, then the syntax would be `System.out.println(add_up());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call the method you need to add () after its name.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Function {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(add_up());
    }

    public static int add_up(){
      int a = 5;
      return a;
    }
}
```

Secondly, you needed to make your method [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) so the static method main can access it.

Comment: What mean static?

Comment: yes, it will be nicer if you write public static int addUp() { int a = 5; return a; }

Comment: Static, refers to the class itself, if you don't have static, it's an instance definition that can only be used by created an instance using the new keyword. for example

Function myFunctionClassInstance = new Function();

Comment: More info about class members and static from Java documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: And can I write this function add_up() to another class?

Comment: @Dominik sure. You should try that as best as you can and if you run into problems create a new question. You will probably want to create an object from your other class, so refer to this page for help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 0):

`add_up` is an instance method, and you have no instance and missing `()`. As is,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(add_up);
}
```

should be

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(new function().add_up());
}
```

but your method uses no instance state, so you could make it `static`. Like,

```
public static int add_up(){
    int a = 5;
    return a;
}
```

And then call it without a specific instance like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(add_up());
}
```

By convention, Java class names start with a capital letter and methods are written in camel case. So `function` should be `Function` (or better, a more unique name) and `add_up` should be `addUp`.

Comment: And can I write this function add_up() to another class?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code. First is in order to call a method you have to provide parameters which you provide in parantesis. As your function does not have any, you simply invoke it with empty brackest: `add_Up()`.

Second your method is an **instance**-member, which assumes you have an instance of the class that contains the class. So you have two opportunitites. Easiest is make your method `static`:

```
public static int add_up(){ ... }
```

Second way is to create an instance of the class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    function f = new function();
    System.out.println(f.add_up());
}
```

Which of the two ways is more appropriate to you depends on your semantics. Does your method belong to a specific **instance**, or does it belong to the class itself?

Anyway be aware that `fuction` is a horrible name for a class. A class is some entity in the world. From a functional persepctive `function` may be such an entity, but I doubt that fits what your class is actually about.